# Read output of avrdude in C program using popen()

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, popen, avrdude

I need to use the same program to program multiple different microcontrollers with `avrdude`. To do this I need to identify the device signature of the connected microcontroller to use the correct `avrdude` command. The only way I've found to do this in-software is to call `avrdude` with an incorrect microcontroller, and read the result where it gives the device signature. I am trying to use `popen()` to read the output of `avrdude`, but I'm not getting anything at all. Here's the code I am using to test `popen()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch, avrBuffer[100];
    FILE *avr;

    avr = popen("sudo avrdude -n -q -p x192d3 -c avrisp2", "r");

    if(avr == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open avrdude");
        return(0);
    }

    fgets(avrBuffer, 100, avr);
    printf("Buffer: %s \n", avrBuffer);

    pclose(avr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Running this gives me this result:

```
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)
avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9749 (probably x192d3)

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Buffer:
```

As you can see, the buffer isn't getting anything added to it. However, when I switch to a different command:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch, avrBuffer[100];
    FILE *avr;

    avr = popen("uname", "r");

    if(avr == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open avrdude");
        return(0);
    }

    fgets(avrBuffer, 100, avr);
    printf("Buffer: %s \n", avrBuffer);

    pclose(avr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get this result, which is what I was expecting:

```
Buffer: Linux
```

Am I using `popen()` wrong, or is there a different way I should be doing this? If it matters, I am running the program on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Maybe avrdude writes its output to `stderr`? What happens if you append `2>&1` to the end of your first argument to `popen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the wording of the [documentation](https://avrdudes.github.io/avrdude/current/avrdude_3.html#Option-Descriptions) for the `-l logfile` option, these messages probably classify as "diagnostics output" and are therefore written to `stderr`, not `stdout` which is captured by `popen`.

One way to solve this would be to redirect `avrdude`'s `stderr` to its `stdout`. E.g. you could append `2>&1` to the end of the first argument to `popen`:

```c
avr = popen("sudo avrdude -n -q -p x192d3 -c avrisp2 2>&1", "r");
```

Comment: Doing this results in the program returning only "Buffer: ", so I'm still not capturing the avrdude output correctly. It does make the avrdude output not show up on the console like it did before though.

Comment: @MaxKelton It works for me. You might want to loop until you have read _all_ lines.

Comment: @thebusybee Ah, that was my problem. Thank you.